# Chart.js Leyendas con valores

Tags: chart.js

En chart.js, es posible agregar los valores a las leyendas? Me refiero a como aparecen en la foto, los valores resaltado en amarillo.

Gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El idioma principal del sitio es el español por lo que te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida.

Comment: Además de traducir la pregunta al español, por favor añade un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema y ayudarte más fácilmente. Completa el [tour] y lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Editado en español. Gracias!

Comment: @Danny gracias por traducirlo. Últimamente recibimos varias preguntas en inglés y estamos intentando mejorar esto. ¿Te molestaría comentar qué no había quedado claro de qué es un sitio en español, o qué te llevó a eso? Gracias